# Ethereum storage implementation at the database level - how is it stored

Tags: storage, state-trie, leveldb, storage-trie

I have read the yellow paper many times as well as various articles, I suppose if I cannot find the answer here - I will look into the code.

My understanding is that each contract account contains a storage root. and you can retrieve the root from the level db.

But what is the value in the leveldb?

Here are some of my questions:

1. LevelDB is key-value, so if we are able to use the storage root to get storage of a contract, then what is the value?
2. I am going to take a wild guess, that the value is the patrica tree?
3. If 2 is true, then isn't it extremely inefficient any time we want to execute the contract - we have to grab the storage of the entire contract.. ? If a contract has a lot of storage, then its potentially extremely slow to do so?
4. Last question - my understanding that all ERC20 token balance information is stored in the storage, then this means if I ICO to 5 million accounts - this means I now have a huge storage that is extremely slow to retrieve? - Given that the entire contract's storage is retrieved all at once.

Comment: The actual on-disk representation of the blockchain is not part of the protocol specification and is thus implementation defined. The answer will vary dramatically depending on the client

Comment: Cpp-ethereum is what I am after

Answer (score 2):

Instructions that store and retrieve data are:

```
    SLOAD: {
        execute:       opSload,
        gasCost:       gasSLoad,
        validateStack: makeStackFunc(1, 1),
        valid:         true,
    },
    SSTORE: {
        execute:       opSstore,
        gasCost:       gasSStore,
        validateStack: makeStackFunc(2, 0),
        valid:         true,
        writes:        true,
    },
```

And here is how they are coded:

```
func opSload(pc *uint64, evm *EVM, contract *Contract, memory *Memory, stack *Stack) ([]byte, error) {
    loc := stack.peek()
    val := evm.StateDB.GetState(contract.Address(), common.BigToHash(loc))
    loc.SetBytes(val.Bytes())
    return nil, nil
}

func opSstore(pc *uint64, evm *EVM, contract *Contract, memory *Memory, stack *Stack) ([]byte, error) {
    loc := common.BigToHash(stack.pop())
    val := stack.pop()
    evm.StateDB.SetState(contract.Address(), loc, common.BigToHash(val))

    evm.interpreter.intPool.put(val)
    return nil, nil
}
```

SetState and GetState are implemented as this:

```
func (self *StateDB) GetState(addr common.Address, bhash common.Hash) common.Hash {
    stateObject := self.getStateObject(addr)
    if stateObject != nil {
        return stateObject.GetState(self.db, bhash)
    }
    return common.Hash{}
}
func (self *StateDB) SetState(addr common.Address, key, value common.Hash) {
    stateObject := self.GetOrNewStateObject(addr)
    if stateObject != nil {
        stateObject.SetState(self.db, key, value)
    }
}

// SetState updates a value in account storage.
func (self *stateObject) SetState(db Database, key, value common.Hash) {
    self.db.journal.append(storageChange{
        account:  &self.address,
        key:      key,
        prevalue: self.GetState(db, key),
    })
    self.setState(key, value)
}

// GetState returns a value in account storage.
func (self *stateObject) GetState(db Database, key common.Hash) common.Hash {
    value, exists := self.cachedStorage[key]
    if exists {
        return value
    }
    // Load from DB in case it is missing.
    enc, err := self.getTrie(db).TryGet(key[:])
    if err != nil {
        self.setError(err)
        return common.Hash{}
    }
    if len(enc) > 0 {
        _, content, _, err := rlp.Split(enc)
        if err != nil {
            self.setError(err)
        }
        value.SetBytes(content)
    }
    self.cachedStorage[key] = value
    return value
}
```

Merkle Patricia trie stores this data:

```
// Account is the Ethereum consensus representation of accounts.
// These objects are stored in the main account trie.
type Account struct {
    Nonce    uint64
    Balance  *big.Int
    Root     common.Hash // merkle root of the storage trie
    CodeHash []byte
}
```

As you can see the `Root     common.Hash` member of the struct holds the hash of the internal storage of the contract. This means, wherever you update contract's storage , the hash is going to change, and as `Account` object is part of the entire trie, the change is going to propagate to higher nodes and the `StateRoot` of the block will change at the end.

So, in short:

1. Contract's storge is modifed only by key->value pairs.
2. Every modification to internal state of the contract implies updating of the whole trie.
3. Even with this design Ethereum is already very inefficient but it was designed to be safe, not fast.

Comment: The Root common.Hash is used to access leveldb to retrieve the entire trie - is that correct? So does this mean - in order to modify anything within the storage, the entire storage has to be retrieve -> then modified -> then put back into leveldb? Is this correct? This is crazy!

Comment: no, `Root common.hash` is only the sub-trie of the contract's storage only

Comment: any modification to the contract's storage will update the entire trie vertically, that's around about 200 modifications per transaction, and that's why Ethereum only works with SSD disks, HDD disks can only do 110 random IOps per second

Comment: "no, Root common.hash is only the sub-trie of the contract's storage only" -> Can you further clarify. Say: I have a ERC20 compliant smart contract and someone just send the contract some Ether in exchange for token. At the implementation level, does it mean the code must retrieve the entire storage trie that belongs to that smart contract via common.Hash. perform the update, and write the tree back into the database. This means if I have 5 million accounts that hold my token, the operation would be extremely slow? Thanks in advance

Comment: only the nodes that have changed are written + the parent nodes of those nodes.

Comment: actually the implementation is very efficient, a change in a trie may produce not a single write to the disk. `geth` has cache and depending on the config it can be so big, that it is going to be enough to hold a lot of key-value pairs without a need to read anything. Also, LevelDB accumulates writes until 128MB of writes are accumulated , reducing IO

Comment: but what if the storage is so large - say I have a huge ICO and 5 million accounts hold balance of my token. This means anytime I update balance of any account, I would need to retrieve the entire storage trie - which includes 5 million accounts? thank you so much for answering

Comment: no, your contract won't update 5 million accounts. First it is impossible because the gas limit of the block is only 7,000,000 and each takes 20,000 gas (if I am not wrong), so there can be only 350 modifications to the storage, of all the contracts of the block combined. Second, Solidity compiles the contract the way the contract accesses storage as key-value pair, only the storage cells that have changed are modifed

Comment: Okay Sorry I didn't make it clear. What I am trying to get to is: If the contract's storage is abnormally large say it already has 5 million accounts in the smart contract. When I only want to update 1 account in the storage - I would need to retrieve the entire storage trie from the database before I can modify anything. is this correct? because based on my understanding, there is no way to retrieve just one storage element from the database without retrieving the entire storage trie the contract owns.

Comment: No. Look at the code above. `GetState()` function uses key (a type of common.Hash)  to lookup the value, it is a single operation.  Why would it need to read the entire trie ? The costly operation here is the `commit` of the entire trie to the disk, a process where all the parent nodes (located higher in the trie) are updated with a new hash.

Comment: are you talking about this line val := evm.StateDB.GetState(contract.Address(), common.BigToHash(loc))? so you are saying it only retrieves the patricia trie's node that contains that storage element? When I was reading CPP ethereum impl, I did not see such thing. This makes a lot more sense now. So the commit will update all the hash - in essence that it will refresh the Root with the new hashes.

Comment: cpp-ethereum looks like abandonware, nobody uses it to run nodes. And I am (myself)  compiling `go-ethereum` into shared libraries to use it in my C++ Ethereum wallet, instead of using native C++ code.